# Export of a Raster Not Preserving Color

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, cartography, dem

I'm trying to make a pretty shaded relief map using the [technique described here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/03/08/an-alternative-to-overlaying-layer-tints-on-hillshades/).

I've done this process several times in the past without any problems but today am perplexed about what is going on.  I have a DEM (IMG format) that I've set the color ramp on.  The next step is to export the DEM to an RGB image so that it can be pan-sharpened with the hillshade.  However, when I run the export tool (right click on the layer, Data, then Export
Data...) the resulting layer is not even close to the color scheme I want.  I've made sure that I've checked the "Use Renderer" and "Force RGB" boxes as described in the article.

Here is my example.  The color scheme I want is on the left, what I'm getting from the export is on the right:
[image: Colors I want and the colors I get]

I've tried to adjust the symbology on the exported raster to get back to what I wanted but I don't know enough about what is going on to get it set right.

What am I missing here?  How do I get my exported image to match the colors I choose in the DEM?

Using ArcGIS 10.2.1, Windows 7.

-- EDIT --
Here is another screenshot of the whole DEM and the whole exported raster.  This one using a different color ramp (Elevation 1) on the left and the exported raster on the right:
[image]

Comment: Is the left what it looks like on screen and the right what is actually being exported? What stretch are you using.. perhaps it's re-stretching the raster on export; try min-max and check the box 'edit value' to make the stretch static.

Comment: The left is what's on the screen when I run the export, the right is what's on the screen after I add the exported layer to the data frame.  I just tried with it set to Min-Max and the edit values box checked - same result.

Comment: Also, I wondered about the re-stretching thing too so I have also tried this with a clipped version of the DEM - and had the same problem there.  It seems I'm doing something totally incorrectly, I just have no idea what.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot of your parameters and the re-added raster layer symbology tab. Perhaps it's got the band order the wrong way around when it's re-added or some really unrealistic stretch/gamma on the bands. Have you viewed the image in paint/photoshop/Gimp?

Comment: I hadn't thought to open the exported image in something other than ArcMap.  If I load it up in Windows Photo Viewer it shows up properly.  Is that an indication that the bands are assigned wrong?

Comment: It's an indication that ArcMap isn't stretching it properly. Change your stretch to None and ensure bands are 1,2 and 3. There must be something in your image aux files that's a bit funny... perhaps deleting them could fix it (just move to another folder in case they're needed). It's looking like it is a duplicate @ChrisW.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think your first comment mostly had it, but it's re-stretched on *import*, not export. See possible duplicate. Kevin, there's a comment on the blog post linked in the question with a response from the author that addresses this. Search for *stretch* in the comments and you should find it pretty quickly.